# MULE example: Sending a CSV file through Email using SMTP

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

Hej,
I'm new in MULE, I try to learn "how to" following examples from Mule's sida: https://www.mulesoft.com/exchange#!/sending-csv-email-smtp?searchTerm=email
I think I did everything well, project is deploing good, but when file is taken exception is thrown and I'v got communicate: 
Exception stack is:
1. Cannot coerce a :binary to a :array (com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.coercion.exception.UnsupportedTypeCoercionException)
  com.mulesoft.weave.model.values.formatting.ArrayFormatTypeCoercionValue:31 (null)
2. Exception while executing: 
payload map {
^
Cannot coerce a :binary to a :array (com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException)
  com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor:124 (null).

Abybody have idea what's happened. Anybody had same problem with that example?

Comment: Seems to be duplicate of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34008860/converting-csv-to-array-using-dataweave

Comment: I don't think so, I have read that answer snd it seems to be not a solution. ;(

Answer (score 0):

Use the following **mimeType** in your DataWeave :-  `<dw:input-payload doc:sample="list_csv.csv" mimeType="application/csv"/>`

So, the full code will be some thing like as follows:-

```
  <smtp:gmail-connector doc:name="Gmail" name="Gmail" validateConnections="true"/>
    <flow name="csv-to-smtpFlow">
        <file:inbound-endpoint doc:name="Poll files" metadata:id="a75d5954-7fb4-4721-85f6-7ee66b793750" path="E:\test" responseTimeout="10000"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform CSV to Map" metadata:id="84d175de-b3c6-4480-af9d-150e736f051e">
            <dw:input-payload doc:sample="list_csv.csv" mimeType="application/csv"/>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload map {
    name: $.name,
    orderId: $.orderId,
    pricePerUnit: $.pricePerUnit as :number,
    units: $.units as :number,
    totalPrice: ($.units * $.pricePerUnit ) as :number
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <logger doc:name="Log the processed objects" level="INFO" message="Processing objects: #[payload]"/>
     <smtp:outbound-endpoint connector-ref="Gmail" doc:name="Send an email via SMTP" from="${mail.from}" host="${smtp.host}" password="${smtp.password}" port="587" responseTimeout="10000" subject="${mail.subject}" to="${mail.to}" user="${smtp.user}"/> 
    </flow>
```

This will solve your issue